# Make webpack resolve context dependencies of the follow kind: require(someVariable)

Tags: node.js, webpack

I was trying to bundle a `nestjs` application to run it in a lambda. But gave up. After a while I tried to do the same with a [freshly created `nestjs` application](https://github.com/x-yuri/nestjs-mysql-webpack) that connects to `mysql`. The [problem](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9489) was that `sequelize` requires `mysql2` [this way](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6.11.0/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js#L66-L86):

```
require(moduleName);
```

Well, it requires the dialect I'm asking it to require, but in this case it was `mysql2`. Apparently `webpack` can't do much about it on its own and bails out. I resolved it [as they suggested](https://github.com/x-yuri/nestjs-mysql-webpack/commit/4037d12b737fbf976bf20d3de04131470e504a52#diff-089f4f2474b64391c42b6e66aed33977e132058d92108f0a63234a7862e1f8b8). But then I thought, "I wonder if `webpack` can replace a specific line in a specific file?" Or rather pretend that it differs. Pretend that instead of `require(moduleName)` it reads `require('mysql2')`.

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338574/how-can-i-replace-files-at-compile-time-using-webpack), but I'm specifically targeting `nodejs`. And I'm concerned about what one might call a [context dependency](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) in `webpack`-speak. A dependency whose request is an expression, not a string.

[`ContextReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/) can't be applied here, because for a single identifier the request is always `.` (such requests are indistinguishible). [`NormalReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) isn't applicable because that's a context dependency. And [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) doesn't seem to be up to the task, because it doesn't let you replace whatever you like, particularly local variables, and function parameters.

If you're interested in bundling a `nodejs` application, you might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635276/how-to-correctly-build-nestjs-app-for-production-with-node-modules-dependencies/59689862#59689862). Here I'm concerned with `webpack` and context dependencies.

P.S. Although I found a solution that doesn't require resolving context dependencies, I might run into it down the road. Or somebody else.

**UPD** And here's a case that can't be worked around like `nestjs` + `sequelize` + `mysql2`. `sequelize-typescript` loads models at runtime:

https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/blob/v2.1.1/src/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.ts#L51

Comment: Yes, there is. And the webpacks docs cover how to do that, so you should be able to just look that up. See the plugin-related answer on [How can I replace files at compile time using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338574/how-can-i-replace-files-at-compile-time-using-webpack)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There's a difference between replacing `require('some string')` and `require(someVar)`. The title might be improved probably though.

Comment: Can you be more specific such as how you decide what to import and if it's at compile time or run time? Also if you're really using require and not es6 imports and why.

Comment: @Dominic I want to replace `require(moduleName)` in [`node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6.11.0/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js#L74) with `require('mysql2')` (since I'm using a single `mysql` database). Or rather make `webpack` think the line reads `require('mysql2')`, not `require(packageName)`.

Comment: Question though: bundles are for clients. Why would your client code ever need to directly talk to your database?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm experimenting with an idea of using `webpack` to tree shake a lambda function.

Comment: That sounds like a rather different topic, making this an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please don't post XY questions. Please edit your post to ask about the thing you're trying to do (not just the solution you're trying to make work. That's just "the thing you tried" that turned out to be problematic, which is an indicator that the solution you thought of is probably not the right one).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, I know what an XY question is. And Y is not problematic. The answer to Y is in the question (for `nestjs` and `sequelize`). And that's what I'm gonna use. But working on it, I got curious, if I can do it the hard way. Like you know, when you don't have the option like you have with `nestjs` and `sequelize`. Who knows, maybe that's what awaits me down the road. So in a way, there's no X. And actually the X itself is questionable. Those few who tried, those I know of, they gave up. I'd like to give it a try. Maybe I'll follow them. Or not. We'll see.

Comment: I haven't been asked about the problem X for a while now, but okay, hopefully my new phrasing resolves your concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer. The provided implementation might not work for you as is. You might need to amend it to work with your version of `webpack`. Also, I'm targeting `nodejs` (not a browser), as such I'm ignoring source maps.

Let's say you have `src/index.js`:

```js
const mysql2 = require('whatever');
```

and the following packages:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql2": "2.3.3",
    "webpack": "5.64.2",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.1"
  }
}
```

and `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const RewriteRequirePlugin = require('./rewrite-require-plugin');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            // {test: path.resolve('src/index.js'),
            // use: [
            //     {loader: path.resolve('rewrite-require-loader.js'),
            //     options: {
            //         search: "'whatever'",
            //         replace: JSON.stringify('mysql2'),
            //     }},
            // ]}
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        // new RewriteRequirePlugin([
        //     [path.resolve('src/index.js'),
        //         "'whatever'",
        //         JSON.stringify('mysql2')],
        // ])
    ],
    stats: {
        modulesSpace: Infinity,
        groupModulesByPath: false,
    }
};
```

It won't build. But if you uncomment the plugin or the loader it will.

`rewrite-require-loader.js`:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function processFile(source, search, replace) {
    const re = `require\\(${escapeRegExp(search)}\\)`;
    return source.replace(
        new RegExp(re, 'g'),
        `require(${replace})`);
}

module.exports = function(source) {
    const options = this.getOptions();
    return processFile(source, options.search, options.replace);
};
```

`rewrite-require-plugin.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const NormalModule = require('webpack/lib/NormalModule');

// https://github.com/webpack/loader-runner/blob/v4.2.0/lib/LoaderRunner.js#L9-L16
function utf8BufferToString(buf) {
    var str = buf.toString("utf-8");
    if(str.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
        return str.substr(1);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function processFile(source, search, replace) {
    source = Buffer.isBuffer(source) ? utf8BufferToString(source) : source;
    const re = `require\\(${escapeRegExp(search)}\\)`;
    return source.replace(
        new RegExp(re, 'g'),
        `require(${replace})`);
}

class RewriteRequirePlugin {
    constructor(rewrites) {
        this.rewrites = rewrites.map(r => [path.resolve(r[0]), r[1], r[2]]);
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('RewriteRequirePlugin', compilation => {
            // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.64.2/lib/schemes/FileUriPlugin.js#L36-L43
            const hooks = NormalModule.getCompilationHooks(compilation);
            hooks.readResource
                .for(undefined)
                .tapAsync("FileUriPlugin", (loaderContext, callback) => {
                    const { resourcePath } = loaderContext;
                    loaderContext.addDependency(resourcePath);
                    loaderContext.fs.readFile(resourcePath, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) return callback(err, data);
                        callback(
                            err,
                            this.rewrites.reduce(
                                (prev, cur) =>
                                    resourcePath == cur[0]
                                        ? processFile(data, cur[1], cur[2])
                                        : data,
                                data));
                    });
                });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = RewriteRequirePlugin;
```